# Pass a parameter with a generic type to a method without knowing the type?

Tags: generics, c#-3.0

I have a class that inherit a base class that take a generic parameter such.

```
Partial Public Class CWsSimulerPrelvBancaire
    Inherits CsBaseService(Of CxSimulerPrelvBancaire)
```

My problem is that i need to pass the base class into a method because i want every class that inherit from that base class to go through that method.

```
  Public Sub ChangerService(ByVal ctl_Service As CsBaseService(Of ???)
        _ctlServiceActif = ctl_Service
        _ctlConteneurService.ActiveViewIndex = ctl_Service.Service
    End Sub
```

The problem is where i added "???" in this code above.. how to set a generic there ? cause we don't need to know which class of type is specified here we just need to know its a CsBaseService(Of anyTypePossible)

I am looking for the cleanest solution to this problem.

Comment: The CWsSimulerPrelvBancaire class must be generic as well.  There is no relationship whatsoever between CsBaseService(Of Foo) and CsBaseService(Of Bar), they are distinct types and only have Object in common.

Answer (score 0):

If the generic type parameter that you pass into CsBaseService can constrain itself to an interface, you could rewrite your method to be generic like so:

```
public void ChangerService<T>(CsBaseService<T> ctl_Service) where T: IInterfaceOfGenericArgument
```